# Why do people sell when demand pushes share price up?

Tags: stocks

Why would owners of a particular share want to sell if they see that there is an increasing demand and that the price is going to increase?

Wouldn't holding onto it and selling at a later time when demand is slowing maximize their profits?

Comment: They certainly don't want to sell when prices are *low*, if they can avoid doing so, right? Buy *low,* sell *high." ... People sell because they want to do something else with the money.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are assuming the price increase will continue. The people selling are assuming that the price increase will *not* continue.

Ultimately that's what a share transaction is: one person would rather have the cash at a particular price / time, and one person would rather have the share.

Comment: A quote attributed to various successful investors: "I never bought at the bottom, and *I always sold too soon.*"

Answer (score 2):

If the price has gone up from what it was when the person bought, he may sell to collect his profit and spend the money.

If someone intends to keep his money in the market, the trick is that you don't know when the price of a given stock will peak. If you could tell the future, sure, you'd buy when the stock was at its lowest point, just before it started up, and then sell at the highest point, just before it started down. But no one knows for sure what those points are. If a stockholder really KNOWS that demand is increasing and the price WILL go up, sure, it would be foolish to sell. But you can never KNOW that. (Or if you have some way that you do know that, please call me and share your knowledge.)